# How to specify parent for bean in Spring annotation config?

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, annotations

How to specify a parent for bean in Spring annotation config?
BaseDao "baseDao" bean should be the parent for

```
@Configuration
public class CategoryContext {
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public CategorySqlHibernateDAO categorySqlHibernateDAO() {
    return new CategorySqlHibernateDAO();
}
}
```

Or Spring 4.2.5 automatically will do this?

Comment: Why not inheritance?

Comment: @aviad, it is inherited, but exact bean should be specified as parent.

Comment: Not sure I understand, You mean CategorySqlHibernateDAO should be specified as a child of BaseDao? (not its parent)

Comment: @avaid, yes, in other words - as said in my post.

Comment: The fact that it inherits from BaseDao is sufficient

Comment: @avaid, thank you! Post this answer, I will accept it. Add please, in comment, if you will be so kind, how define abstract bean with some attributes in Java configuration? Or send to arthur-dn@mail.ru (million times thank you!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance is sufficient. No need to define anything extra.
CategorySqlHibernateDAO should extend BaseDao.

Regarding your last comment, abstract classes don't need any further annotations or definitions - Just the concrete classes that extend them. 
You can define Configuraions class which would be abstract with any fields/methods/abstract methods you want, and than when you extend this class put the required annotations in it. Hope this helps...